# MySQL query return multiple substring occurrences in a field using substring_index

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to return all occurrences delimited by a certain pattern in the same field using substring_index function. Currently I can get the exact substring I'm searching in the field, but only the first occurrence of it. Have no idea how to get all matches and loop them after separately? Thanks for any help!

```
$query = "SELECT substring_index(substring_index(field_name, '<intp>', -1), '</intp>', 1) AS 'intp' FROM #__table_name WHERE id = '$id'";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$intp = $row["intp"];
echo $intp;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `strpos` in php instead of `substring_index` in MySql?

Comment: Just select the entire field and use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in PHP.